# API or dataset of fashion products

Tags: api, fashion

I'm looking for something like either an API that will let you query a catalog of products by category (for example trousers or shirts) and get comprehensive product information back or this same thing in the form of an offline dataset. The vendors doesn't matter but it has to be in fashion.

Comment: have you found anything?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered tying together a couple of Ebay's Buy API  endpoints like the Taxonomy API to get the category id combined with their "Browse" endpoint?

Taxonomy Endpoint :

https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/commerce/taxonomy/static/overview.html

Browse Endpoint Example (using categoryID):

https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/buy/browse/resources/item/methods/getItemsByItemGroup#_samples

Comment: is this api free?

Comment: There is both a free and payed version. The free version is rate limited.